# Проблемы с только-что созданым приложением Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Я создал чистый проект на Xamarin, Android App, по заданию нужно сделать простенький калькулятор. Захожу в Main.xaml и в дизайнере выдает ошибку

> This project contains resources that were not compiled successfully, rendering might be affected

При дебаге выдает следуйщее

> 'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'Main'

Обрыл пол интернета, ndk поставил, ребилдил, чистил(не знаю зачем, думал повезет), перепробовал кучу версий SDK Tools(кто-то говорил помогло). И вот застрял: дебажить не могу, ничего сделать не могу.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: поставьте 32- и 64-битные jdk, удалите файл и добавьте заново. кроме того, попробуйте (зайдя в **path2android-sdk\tools\bin** ) обновить sdk командами **sdkmanager packages "build-tools;27.0.3"**. цифры вводить в соответствии с minimun, target и compile фреймворками: все они должны быть у Вас в path2android-sdk\build-tools